# I want to display only the current culture currency symbol in rdlc report textbox. Is there a Keyword?

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I could ot find any keywords that will get me the currency symbol.Help will b greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left(FormatCurrency(0,0),1) gives the currency symbol